# display images in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, relational-database

I am trying to display the the first image from the albums table that belongs to the a post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums, dependent: :destroy
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

and in the post index I wanted to display the one of the images that belongs to a post in the post/index page

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [ :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy] #:show,


  def index
     @albums = Album.all
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @user = @post.user(params[:id])
    @album = Album.new
    @album.post_id = @post.id
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    if current_user
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

      if @post.save
         redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' 
      else
         render action: 'new'
       end
      end
    end
end
```

this is the albums controller

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @album = Album.new(album_params)
    @album.post_id = params[:post_id]

    @album.save
    redirect_to post_path(@album.post), notice: 'photo added successfully'
  end

end
```

below is the views/posts/index.html.erb page

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.title %>
     <% post.albums.each do |album| %>
       <%= image_tag album.image.url(:thumb) %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

what do I need to do so that I can display the first image in a post?

Comment: How are you handling the images? Can you please post the Image model?

Comment: @Gotjosh instead of images i just used the album model which has post_id and image

Comment: So what you want to do is display the first image of each album?

Comment: @Gotjosh I want to display the first image of the album that belongs to a specific post

Comment: Did you tried my response below? If you have multiple images you should do album.images.first.url

Comment: @Gotjosh I did and it worked and if there are more than one images and i want to display only one, like the first one how do I go about it?

Comment: With the code above you get to display the first image by using images.first, can you please specify how the code looks now so that I can update my answer :)

Comment: I implemented the solution you gave me and updated the code above. how do you go about showing only one image

Comment: I have updated my answer go take a look.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need to do is loop the relation to display the image:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <%= post.title %>
 <% post.albums.each do |album| %> 
   <%= image_tag album.image_url %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you'd like to only display one image (the first one) this could be done.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <%= post.title %>
 <%= image_tag post.albums.first.image_url %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked and if there are more than one images and i want to display only one, like the first one how do I go about it?

Comment: @ErycBrown Would you please accept the answer if that helped you out? :)

Answer (score 0):

To display the first image you can use

```
<%= image_tag post.albums.first.image_url %>
```